# How to create an icon from static resource twice?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a resource in `Application.Resources` (svg icon):

```
<Canvas x:Key="IconAdd" Width="48" Height="48">
...
```

I'm trying to use it in multiple buttons like that:

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
        <Viewbox>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource IconAdd}"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <TextBlock>Button text</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

The problem is that the icon appears only in the last button.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2899697/1943849) I've understood this is because in WPF each Visual can only have one parent.

I feel I need to put an icon to a data template, but how to use it in my case?

Comment: That happens because that Canvas is static (one instance for all your application), you could try with a DataTemplate, I am not exactly sure how, but that should be the way

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `x:Shared` attribute. Here is the link to [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247577/wpf-usercontrols-image-disappears-even-with-xshared-false), and [MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As I've expected, I need to put an icon to a data template:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="IconAddTemplate">
     <Canvas Width="48" Height="48">
...
```

And then I can use it like that:

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
        <Viewbox>
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource IconAddTemplate}" />
        </Viewbox>
        <TextBlock>Button text</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```